# NodeJS serve image from base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, base64

I have a Route on my Meteor App:

```
    this.route("/userimg/:id", function(){
        console.log("hello");
        img_base64 = Meteor.users.findOne(this.params.id).userimage;
        this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });

    },{where: 'server'});
```

With this Route I want to serve Userimages from my Mongo-Collection.
I have a base64 encoded image in my Collection and saving it to varibale `img_base64`.
My Question is, what do I need to do with my base64 variable to respond it as a png?
I need somthing like `this.response.end(img_base64,....)`.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's literally all you need (assuming `img_base64` is a string):

```
this.response.end(img_base64, 'base64');
```